# Can I change Apple IDs?

Tags: iphone, itunes, ios, ipod, apple-id

I originally used my Apple ID with my daughter's iPod and now iPhone so that her purchases would be linked to my credit card. I now know that wasn't necessary.

I'd like to know how to change this so I can have her get her own Apple ID so her music, apps, etc. don't sync with my iOS devices.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can sort of do this.

You can't make a new account for your daughter and then move existing purchases to be owned by your her new account.  You can use those purchases on her iPod though.

If she already has her own computer account and itunes install just move over to a new iTunes account and make new purchases there.  Change your password and move on.   She will no longer be able to buy with your account. You may need to log in every so often so she can get updates of the apps that were purchased by your account but otherwise things will work fine.

If you have to split her a new iTunes account out of your existing account it's a bit more complex.  There are a number of ways you can pull this off; here's how I would pull this off.

1. Make a computer account for your daughter.
2. Make a new Apple account for your daughter.
3. Change your password.
4. Authorize this new iTunes with your ID.  It's under Store->Authorize This Computer...  This lets her use content you've purchased with out logging in as you.
5. Use Home Sharing to move your old purchases to the new iTunes.
6. Sync her iPhone over to this new iCloud account.

At this point you can remove the purchases for her from your account.  They are in her account and will install and play on her iPhone.  She doesn't have for password and those apps you've already purchased for her are still owned by you.  They won't update without your password.   You'll have to log in for her every so often so that things can update. It'll prompt both on the phone and on the computer when it needs it.

Comment: Rather than home sharing you can put the Media in a shared location on the HD, and point iTunes to it. You can then transfer the songs/apps/etc to her iTunes and authorize her iTunes account with your ID

Answer (score 1):

I would set up a brand new Apple ID under her email address.

You can then transfer the files on your computer to her iTunes account. You will then need to authorize her account to play the purchases made on your account.

Once that has been done she will have full access to all the songs you bought her, and be able to make new purchases that will not sync to your devices.