# Sync an iDevice apps with two Apple IDs

Tags: applications, data-synchronization, apple-id

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [2 Apple IDs on one device?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50175/2-apple-ids-on-one-device)

I was planning on getting a new iPhone and I want to give my old one to my younger brother, both of us have different Apple ID. The question is, can I retain my old apps on the old iPhone while syncing/installing my brother's purchased apps in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. I use two Apple IDs on my iPhone 4S.

It is not the most comfortable setup though: You must switch IDs in Settings>iTunes & App Stores. Just tap on your Apple ID and select Sign Out. Then log in with your brother's Apple ID.

I don't think the iPhone will pull the apps your brother bought when he signs in with his Apple ID. He will have to install them manually.

Comment: It won't automatically download his apps when he signs in, but they should appear in the "Purchased" tab of the App Store.