# Separate User accounts, separate iCloud Music Library

Tags: itunes, icloud, music, high-sierra, apple-music

I have iMac with 2 user accounts. I want to have separate iCloud music Library for this two accounts. Since I have two accounts I have two Apple Music memberships. 
And when I’m trying to turn it on on the second account i see this:
[image]

Yes It is - it’s link to my other account there. So I cannot really unlink it. Any way to separate accounts can have separate Apple Music through iTunes?

Answer (score 1):

The whole thing is described at [View and remove your associated devices in iTunes](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204074). 
It seems Apple allows to connect several devices, without any problem, but at the same time it has some restrictions and limitations.

> You can have **ten devices** (no more than **five of them computers**) associated with your Apple ID and iTunes at one time.

You are getting this message because of [their AppleID policy](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204074#about):

> When you try to associate another Apple ID with a device that was already associated, you might see a message that says, "This device is associated with another Apple ID. You cannot associate this device with another Apple ID for [number] days." Depending on when you associated your device with your Apple ID, you might need to wait up to 90 days to associate the device with another Apple ID.

The iTunes account scenario and a 90 day wait between transfers is a seriously ridiculous constraint. But it feels there's no other way-around as per discussion here: [Multiple Apple IDs on one Mac](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4504983?start=0&tstart=0)

Comment: Your answer is summary of a problem - I can have one Apple ID with 10 devices, but can I have 1 device connected to 10 Apple IDs? It’s other way around

Comment: @Kuba then have a look into [a similar topic](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50175/2-apple-ids-on-one-device). Using multiple Apple IDs might be confusing and cause issues with accessing purchased content or using some services, [they state](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204053)

Comment: Since there is two separate user accounts I don’t want to mix them with one Apple ID, since there is 2 people actually using iMac. Why this is bad thing?

Comment: It's a bad thing because Apple prefers only one user per device. They do the same with iPhones (iPads are a little forgiving but the rules still apply). It becomes very troublesome for Apple and yourself when you have multiple accounts/users. While with a Macbook its realistic for multiple users to have accounts, but not different Apple services amongst them.

Comment: @MelvinJefferson are there any other restrictions like that in MacOS? Or it’s only iCloud Music? iCloud itself seems to work fine...

Comment: Only with Apple digital services like iCloud, Music, Device backups, purchases made from iTunes or the app store, music and storage subscriptions and account details.